# Troubleshooting SignalR in a .NET Client Distributed Scenario

Tags: c#, signalr

I have an app layered like this: WPF -> WCF -> BLL -> DAL -> DB. The WCF layer starts the SignalR host. The BLL uses SignalR to notify the clients. The WPF is the client that receives SignalR notifications.

My problem is that it works on my laptop, however, the same code, when deployed to a distributed environment (WPF runs on my laptop and WCF runs on another server), doesn't result in the WPF client getting the SignalR notifications.

I have two questions:

1. Is there something I'm doing incorrectly (see code below)? I thought maybe using `localhost` in the config files could be an issue, but googling hasn't shed any light on that.
2. What are the typical troubleshooting procedures for something like this? I'm not sure where to start.

**WCF host starts SignalR:**

```
    private void StartSignalRHost()
    {
        var url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["signalrAddress"];
        WebApplication.Start<Startup>(url);
    }
```

**BLL invokes SignalR:**

```
    private static void OnDatabaseItemAdded(object sender, EventArgs<string> e)
    {
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<PrestoHub>();
        hubContext.Clients.All.OnDatabaseItemAdded("snuh");
    }
```

**WPF client receives SignalR notification:**

```
    private void InitializeSignalR()
    {
        var signalrAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["signalrAddress"];
        var hubConnection = new HubConnection(signalrAddress);
        var prestoHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("PrestoHub");
        prestoHubProxy.On<string>("OnDatabaseItemAdded", OnDatabaseItemAdded);
        hubConnection.Start();
    }

    private void OnDatabaseItemAdded(string data)
    {
        Refresh();
    }
```

**The config files have this in them:**

Note: `localhost` is replaced with the server name in the WPF config.

```
<add key="signalrAddress" value="http://localhost:8084"/>
```

Comment: Does your hub override the name? If not, SignalR likes to rename the hub, e.g. "prestoHub".

Comment: Also, have you verified that the client is actually connecting to the server?

Comment: @JoelLucsy It does not. There are no attributes on the PrestoHub class. And it works locally. I'm thinking it may be a permissions issue since my laptop is in a different domain than the WCF server. But I'm just guessing at this point.

Comment: How would I verify that the client is actually connecting? No exceptions are occurring when I step through the code on the client.

Comment: hubConnection.Start().Wait();

Comment: @GustavoArmenta Thank you for that tip. Indeed, I'm getting an error: `The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.` Now the question is why is that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research and trial and error, the issue was using `localhost` in the config of the server.

I had to change this:

```
<add key="signalrAddress" value="http://localhost:8084"/>
```

To this:

```
<add key="signalrAddress" value="http://servername:8084"/>
```

The issue is explained [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1881253.aspx/1?More%20SelfHost%20Documentation).

> The URL is used to open an HttpListener. With the URL above (the
>   localhost one) this HttpListener will accept requests from
>   `http://localhost` only. Other, equivalent URLs do not work:

```
http://127.0.0.1
http://110.120.130.140
http://myserver
```